# android pinch zoom scale view scrollbar moves

Tags: android, view, scrollbar, scale

i have a view in linear layout. the app is music notation which is a series of musical bars which line wrap so they always less than width of screen (no horizontal scrolling). there is a vertical scrollbar when the music score gets too big for the view. so far so good. i can scroll up and down fine.

now i'm implementing pinch zoom, i set up an onScale in a ScaleGestureDetector, save the scale factor, invalidate and in onDraw i use the scale factor like this canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

it scales the view ok except its not doing exactly what i want. i want the drawing area of the canvas to scale as it does but the scrollbar to stay in place, but zooming sends it off to the side, out of view.

any idea how to scale the view but not the scrollbar?

BTW, i can recalculate where to line wrap my music bars by applying the scalefactor to the width, its really just a problem with the scrollbar display.

can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)?

Comment: i'm looking now. i just changed my View to ScrollView and the display looks the same and pinch zoom works. but now when i get onScroll callbacks in the GestureDetector the distanceY is always 1. in the View base class, i got the acutual drag amount. anyhow, thanks for the tip, this may help.

Comment: actually, when i put the scrollbar back on the right, then i zoom, the scrollbar moves off screen so i'm not sure what the advantage of ScrollView over View is, but it doesn't seem to help my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way. I needed to decouple the drawing of the scrollbar from the drawing of the main music notation view. that way I can zoom the main notation view without affecting the scroll bar.

so I use linear layout to create 2 views -

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    100));
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            Globals.mMainView = new MainView(context);
            Globals.mMainView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 60));
            layout.addView(Globals.mMainView);

            Globals.mScrollbarView = new ScrollbarView(context);
            Globals.mScrollbarView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
            layout.addView(Globals.mScrollbarView);
```

then I remove display of scrollbars from MainView and put them in ScrollbarView.

then I use onScroll events in ScrollbarView to control scrolling in MainView. I have to remember to return the actual display length of MainView from ScrollbarView.computeVerticalScrollRange so the scroll bar size shows up ok.

since I have reference to both views saved as globals, its easy for them to talk to each other as necessary.